# Reinstall grub on mbr without copying modules' files or config

Tags: grub2, boot-loader, mbr

if i issued

```
grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sdx
```

`grub-install` will write the bootsector to the mbr and try to copy the modules to the boot partition, i don't want that, all i want is to rewrite the bootsector to mbr and quit without copying any files.is that possible with `grub-install` ?

Answer (score 0):

`grub-install` is going to copy its images, by default to /boot. There's no mention of a way to disable that, but you can tell it to install to another location to leave your /boot alone. For example: `grub-install --target=i386-pc --boot-directory=/tmp/delete/me/later /dev/sdx`

Be careful with that though. I get the sense `grub-install` was designed that way for a reason.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Invoking-grub_002dinstall